# Grails: How do I retrieve records by a specific property?

Tags: grails

I am creating a basic CRUD application with a Person entity:

```
class Person {
    public int Age;
    ...
    public int getAge() {
        return this.Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int AgeToSet) {
        this.Age = AgeToSet;
    }
}
```

I have a controller and I want to retrieve all Persons with an age of 20:

```
def filter = {
    def c = Person.createCriteria();
    def persons = c.list{
         eqProperty("Age", "20");
     }
    [persons: persons];
}
```

But this is not working and is, instead, giving me the error:

```
ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace:
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Age of: project.Person
    at     org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: That's not how domain classes are configured in Grails/GORM. You can do it that way but it's absurdly verbose. In Groovy if you don't specify the scope of a variable (`public`, `private`, etc.) then it is publict, and is actually a "property", not a field - the compiler will automatically add a getter and setter for you. Not 'virtually' in the metaclass, but for real in the bytecode, so they're visible to Java and Groovy. Delete `public` from the age property declaration (in addition to the case fix already applied) and delete both the getter and setter methods (i.e. just have `int age`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

- Your `Age` needs to start with lowercase: `age`.
- Your criteria is wrong, you want to use `eq`. `eqProperty` compares two properties, but you only need one and a value.
- Your comparision must be with an `int`, like this: `eq("myage", 20)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this query is so simple, you may want to just use a DynamicFinder: http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#finders

With a Dynamic Finder, you could simplify the query to:

```
def persons = Person.findAllByAge(20)
```

Just a suggestion. I use Dynamic Finders as my primary query method. If I need a query that is more complex, I'll resort to a `.createCriteria` and then a `.executeQuery` which takes HQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually modified my criteria request by allowing filtering based on multiple object properties. So it is being used not only for age, but also for height, gender, etc.